# Is there difference between vue component creating with Vue.extend and empty object?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Is there difference between these ways of component creating?

`Vue.component('name', Vue.extend({ ... }))`

`Vue.component('name', { ... })`

if no what is `Vue.extend` aim?